# Spring-Kafka never hits Kafka listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm building a simple consumer and decided to migrate over to Springboot and the springkafka depenedency to make the process simple.

The environment/config values are interpolated from a mix of environment + properties file in Spring. All the values look fine. I have data on the topic and I can consume it from something like kafkacat or console consumer.

#### Problem

method with `@kafkalistener` never gets invoked. I debug the code and it just says "build successful". It will call the setup, the configuration and the factories, but the consumer listener just doesn't get invoked..

#### Attempt To Resolve

**Consumer**

```
@Service
public class CyclicConsumerService {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic", groupId = "test-group-id")
    public void avroConsumer(GenericRecord message) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

**Configuration Setup**

```
...

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

...

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,
            GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(retrieveConsumerConfigs());
    }
```

#### retrieveConsumerConfiguration method

```
    public Map<String, Object> retrieveConsumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, retrieveArgument(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, retrieveArgument(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG);
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, retrieveArgument(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG));
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS);
        addSaslProperties(props);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, TopicNameStrategy.class.getName());
        return props;
    }
```

```
    private String retrieveArgument(String argName) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty(argName),
                "Unable to resolve non-existent Kafka environment variable");
    }
```

## Logs

```
: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Initializing the Kafka consumer
: Successfully logged in.
: Created SSL context with keystore null, truststore null
: Added sensor with name fetch-throttle-time
Added sensor with name connections-closed:
Added sensor with name connections-created:
Added sensor with name successful-authentication:
Added sensor with name successful-reauthentication:
Added sensor with name successful-authentication-no-reauth:
Added sensor with name failed-authentication:
Added sensor with name failed-reauthentication:
Added sensor with name reauthentication-latency:
Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
Added sensor with name bytes-received:
Added sensor with name select-time:
Added sensor with name io-time:
Added sensor with name heartbeat-latency
Added sensor with name join-latency
Added sensor with name sync-latency
Added sensor with name commit-latency
Added sensor with name bytes-fetched
Added sensor with name records-fetched
Added sensor with name fetch-latency
Added sensor with name records-lag
Added sensor with name records-lead
Kafka version: 2.3.1
Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
Kafka startTimeMs: 1606869543614
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Kafka consumer initialized
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Subscribed to topic(s): my-topic
Initializing ExecutorService
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Sending FindCoordinator request to broker xxxx:9093 (id: -1 rack: null)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Received user wakeup
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Initiating connection to node xxxx:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address xxxx
Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST
Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=xxxx;mechs=[SCRAM-SHA-512]
Setting SASL/SCRAM_SHA_512 client state to SEND_CLIENT_FIRST_MESSAGE
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Raising WakeupException in response to user wakeup
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
Shutting down ExecutorService
Removed sensor with name connections-closed:
Removed sensor with name connections-created:
Removed sensor with name successful-authentication:
Removed sensor with name successful-reauthentication:
Removed sensor with name successful-authentication-no-reauth:
Removed sensor with name failed-authentication:
Removed sensor with name failed-reauthentication:
Removed sensor with name reauthentication-latency:
Removed sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
Removed sensor with name bytes-sent:
Removed sensor with name bytes-received:
Removed sensor with name select-time:
Removed sensor with name io-time:
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Kafka consumer has been closed
test-group-id: Consumer stopped
```

Comment: have you tried to add your factory to `@KafkaListener`?

Comment: also consider adding `@Import({KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})` to your kafka config class

Comment: `>[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-group-id] Raising WakeupException in response to user wakeup` - this implies that something is stopping the container (or application context) during startup. Post the complete (stripped down) application someplace.